# Query to fill the gaps(data) between records SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table, containing Fuel Price changes.

```
-------------------------------
|    Date    |  Fuel  | Price |
-------------------------------
| 10.07.2018 | Petrol | 4     |
| 13.07.2018 | Petrol | 5     |
| 15.07.2018 | Petrol | 6     |
| 11.07.2018 | Diesel | 8     |
| 14.07.2018 | Diesel | 10    |
-------------------------------
```

I need to make an SQL query that fills the day gaps and shows a report of everyday fuel prices.

Query result:

```
-------------------------------
|    Date    |  Fuel  | Price |
-------------------------------
| 10.07.2018 | Petrol | 5     |
| 11.07.2018 | Petrol | 5     |
| 12.07.2018 | Petrol | 5     |
| 13.07.2018 | Petrol | 4     |
| 14.07.2018 | Petrol | 4     |
| 15.07.2018 | Petrol | 6     |
| 11.07.2018 | Diesel | 8     |
| 12.07.2018 | Diesel | 8     |
| 13.07.2018 | Diesel | 8     |
| 14.07.2018 | Diesel | 10    |
-------------------------------
```

For bonus points: if query is run today(let's say today = 17.07.2018), query should also print all the fuel prices till today:

Query2 result:
all rows from Query1 result +

```
-------------------------------
|    Date    |  Fuel  | Price |
-------------------------------
| 16.07.2018 | Petrol | 6     |
| 17.07.2018 | Petrol | 6     |
| 15.07.2018 | Diesel | 10    |
| 16.07.2018 | Diesel | 10    |
| 17.07.2018 | Diesel | 10    |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your attempts

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As soon as I finish my work shift I will post my current attempts.

Comment: A hint/tip to start with: LAG.

Comment: I suggest you outer join to a _calendar table_ to do this. This will fill nay number of days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first query, you can do this using a hierarchical query in combination with lead to find the next row's date. The following works aross most versions of Oracle:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT to_date('10/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Petrol' fuel, 4 price FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('13/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Petrol' fuel, 5 price FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('15/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Petrol' fuel, 6 price FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('11/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Diesel' fuel, 7 price FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('14/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Diesel' fuel, 10 price FROM dual)
SELECT dt -1 + LEVEL dt,
       fuel,
       price
FROM   (SELECT dt,
               fuel,
               price,
               LEAD(dt, 1, dt) OVER (PARTITION BY fuel ORDER BY dt) - dt num_days_to_next_price
        FROM   your_table)
CONNECT BY PRIOR dt = dt
           AND PRIOR fuel = fuel
           AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS not NULL
           AND LEVEL <= num_days_to_next_price
ORDER BY fuel DESC, dt;

DT          FUEL        PRICE
----------- ------ ----------
10/07/2018  Petrol          4
11/07/2018  Petrol          4
12/07/2018  Petrol          4
13/07/2018  Petrol          5
14/07/2018  Petrol          5
15/07/2018  Petrol          6
11/07/2018  Diesel          7
12/07/2018  Diesel          7
13/07/2018  Diesel          7
14/07/2018  Diesel         10
```

In the lead analytic function, I use the optional second and third parameters do set the number of rows to look-ahead (1), and the value to put if we're on the last row in the partition, which we simply put as the same date as that of the partition's last row.

The second query is actually very similar to the first query, the only differences being:

- filter the rows returned so that there isn't a date higher than the date you're interested in
- in the lead function, instead of choosing a default value of dt for the last row in the partition (aka group), choose your specific date plus 1 day (we need to add the extra day because we want to display both the start and the end day; if we didn't, our query would display the start and the previous day to the last day).

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT to_date('10/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Petrol' fuel, 4 price FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('13/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Petrol' fuel, 5 price FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('15/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Petrol' fuel, 6 price FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('11/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Diesel' fuel, 7 price FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('14/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'Diesel' fuel, 10 price FROM dual)
SELECT dt -1 + LEVEL dt,
       fuel,
       price
FROM   (SELECT dt,
               fuel,
               COALESCE(price, LAG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY fuel ORDER BY dt)) price,
               LEAD(dt, 1, to_date('17/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fuel ORDER BY dt) - dt num_days_to_next_price
        FROM   your_table
        WHERE  dt <= to_date('17/07/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
CONNECT BY PRIOR dt = dt
           AND PRIOR fuel = fuel
           AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS not NULL
           AND LEVEL <= num_days_to_next_price
ORDER BY fuel DESC, dt;

DT          FUEL        PRICE
----------- ------ ----------
10/07/2018  Petrol          4
11/07/2018  Petrol          4
12/07/2018  Petrol          4
13/07/2018  Petrol          5
14/07/2018  Petrol          5
15/07/2018  Petrol          6
16/07/2018  Petrol          6
17/07/2018  Petrol          6
11/07/2018  Diesel          7
12/07/2018  Diesel          7
13/07/2018  Diesel          7
14/07/2018  Diesel         10
15/07/2018  Diesel         10
16/07/2018  Diesel         10
17/07/2018  Diesel         10
```